# Include content of other components inside my sidebar component Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to include content of my components such as add, delete, modify with my sidebar. In the beginning, I had my sidebar html in app.component.html which was showing results as I wanted, example if I click on delete, sidebar would be there, if I click on "add" link, sidebar will appear like this with addition to my form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNIdd.png

Then I created another component named sidebar and put my sidebar content in there because I do not want sidebar to appear for all components such as my login page. Now when I would route to "add" component, my form would look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbZj1.png and my "sidebar" component like this: [sidebar.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVLc6.png)

I wanted to combine these components so it would display the way it is in the first picture, however, after I added  on my top of my add.component.html, results were like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPTId.png.

I have been trying to fix this from past few days with no success. PLEASE HELP ME!!!
Additionally, let me know if need me to include sidebar.component.css or add.component.css

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**add.component.html**

```
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<div class="container">
  <div class="contact__wrapper shadow-lg mt-n9">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-lg-7 contact-form__wrapper p-5 order-lg-1">
        <form
          #addForm="ngForm"
          action="POST"
          class="contact-form form-validate"
          novalidate="novalidate"
        >
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="required-field" for="name">Student Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Name"
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="credits">ID</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  name="ID"
                  placeholder="ID"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="type">Gender</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  name="type"
                  placeholder="M/F"
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  name="code"
                  placeholder="123-123-1234"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="required-field">Email</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="email@gmail.com"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="required-field">Address: </label>
                <textarea
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  name="address"
                  rows="4"
                  placeholder="This course teaches....."
                ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
              <button
                type="submit"
                name="submit"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                (click)="addCourse(addForm)"
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**sidebar.component.html**

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li>
      <a (click)="routeFunction('Dashboard')">
        <span class="link_name">Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a (click)="routeFunction('Add')">
        <span class="link_name">Add</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a (click)="routeFunction('Update')">
        <span class="link_name">Update</span>
      </a>
    </li>
<li>
  <a (click)="routeFunction('Delete')">
    <span class="link_name">Delete</span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a (click)="routeFunction('Setting')">
    <span class="link_name">Setting</span>
  </a>
</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<section class="home-section">
  <div class="home-content">
    <i class="bx bx-menu"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css'],
})
export class SidebarComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  routeFunction(name: string) {
    this.router.navigate([name]);
  }
}
```

**add.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.css'],
})
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
  minDate: String = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en');
  student: Students

  constructor(private studentService: StudentService) {}

  public ngOnInit() {}

  add(addForm: NgForm) {
    this.studentService.addStudent(addForm.value).subscribe(
      (response: Students) => {
        addForm.reset();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```